# What is the reason behind breaking the for/ map into two separate components?

Tags: reactjs

What is the reason behind breaking the for/ map into two separate components? Can this be even clubbed into one?

Stuff.js

```
class Stuff extends Component {
  render() {
    if(this.props.stuffs){
     stuffItems = this.props.stuffs.map(stuff => {
      return(
      <StuffItem key={stuff.title} stuff={stuff}>
            )
      })
     }
    return (
     <div className="Stuff"> {stuffItems} </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Stuffitem.js

```
class StuffItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

    <li className="Stuff"> {this.props.stuff.title}</li>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can choose to combine them if it's simple. Breaking into sub components is the same reason why you refactor any app into multiple functions (easier to read, test, reuse, extend etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to separate elements to another components.

Basically to separate components when you want to encapsulate functionality of a component. for example, if your `<StuffItem />` component had some special functionality, it would be a good practice to separate it.

In other words: **Separation of Concern**

So you can just write:

```
class Stuff extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul className="Stuff">
                {this.props.stuffs.map(stuff => (
                    <li className="Stuff">{stuff.title}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple; **composability** and **reusability**. You could easily just do everything in the `Stuff` component, but maybe you'd like to able to use `StuffItem` somewhere else. It also seperates the list and list-items logic and behaviour, which makes it easier to read, test and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing inherently right or wrong about how you (or someone else) chose to write your example... In this specific case, sure, there wouldn't really be any harm in moving `StuffItem`'s code inline.

However, Components are meant to be *reusable*. If you have another component which "accepts" `StuffItem`s as children, or perhaps `StuffItem` is a little more complex (different behaviour depending on the props you supply it), then it makes sense to keep them separate.